# multiplication of random numbers different from zero

Tags: c++, product, draw

I have a code that generates 10 random numbers and I need to calculate the sum and product of the non-zero numbers and display which numbers have been multiplied. I already have most of the code but I have no idea how to multiply numbers that are nonzero and then display them. Can someone help me?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "draws 10 numbers:" << endl;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << endl;

    srand(time(0));
    int sum=0;
    int product=1;

    for(int i=0, value=0; i<10; i++, sum+=value, product*=value) 
    {
        value = rand()%10+0;
        Sleep(1000);
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    Sleep(1000);
    cout << "the sum is " << sum <<endl;
    cout << "the product is " << product <<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Well, can you multiply with pen and paper these numbers and write the result? 5,2,9,1? I ask because I am not sure what your problem is.

Comment: Use an if statement.  If the number you generated is zero, don't add and multiply by it.

Comment: You need to use [`if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) statements: `if (value != 0) { ...do these steps... }`

Comment: Change your loop setup to `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)` to avoid the confusion of fancy-coding. Do the rest inside the body (or in setup code before the loop). I bet things clarify by themselves then.

Comment: Instead of the repeatedly recommended `if` you could more elegantly just make sure that no 0 is drawn as a random number. Especailly here `value=0;` and here `value = rand()%10+0;`, the zeros are going to haunt you.

Comment: Maybe `value = rand()%10+0;` should be `value = rand()%10+1;`. Then you'd never generate a zero.

Comment: Since C++11, there are better ways to generate random numbers: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution , but please explain whether you have to draw 10 numbers and multiply *only* the non zero values or your task is to multiply *10* random numbers, all of them different from zero.

Comment: There are betters ways to do all of this in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, it is easier to read and understand if we move the addition and multiplication out of the for loop header.

```cpp
int sum = 0;
int value = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  int value = rand() % 10;
  sum += value;
  product *= value;
  std::cout << value << std::::endl;
}
```

Next, we only want to do the multiplication `if` the `value` is not equal `0`.

```cpp
int sum = 0;
int value = 1;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
  int value = rand() % 10;
  sum += value;

  if(value != 0)
  {
    product *= value;
  }

  std::cout << value << std::::endl;
}
```

So the whole program looks like this.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "draws 10 numbers:" << std::endl;

  srand(time(0));
  int sum = 0;
  int product = 1;
  int multiplied = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    int value = rand() % 10;
    sum += value;

    if(value != 0)
    {
      product *= value;
      multiplied += 1;
    }

    std::cout << value << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
  std::cout << "the sum is " << sum << std::endl;
  std::cout << "the product is " << product << std::endl;
  std::cout << "numbers multiplied is " << multiplied << std::endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! but I still need to display the numbers that have been multiplied and I have no idea how to do this

Comment: Sorry, I have to display how many numbers have been multiplied and not what have been multiplied

Comment: If you generate the numbers 1,0,3,2 for example, you need to print sum: 6, product, 6, numbers multiplied: 3?

Comment: that's exactly what it's supposed to look like

Comment: Then you can add another counter variable, and every time you go into the if statement where (value != 0) you can increment the counter. Then print the counter variable at the end